# Record video in 480x480 resolution with iPhone/iPad? How to set this resolution in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, video, resolution, record

Here's the problem: I want to know if it is possible to record video with iPhone/iPad in resolution 480x480 ? And how this is going to be set programmatically in Xcode? Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

use camera of [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage%5d)

```
.... [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(480, 480)];
```

and for GPUImage [this link](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2012/02/12/introducing-gpuimage-framework) is also useful.